# How to disable accessibility keys (Sticky Keys, Toggle Keys etc.) in case of focus lost or crash?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, exception, focus

I am trying to disable accessibility keys for my game (through a DLL) following [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416808(v=vs.85).aspx#disable_the_accessibility_shortcut_keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#disable_the_accessibility_shortcut_keys)
and it works except it also permanently disables the keys when the game loses focus or in a case of a crash.

So I need the app to restore keys when losing focus and when it crashes.

```
export double accesskeys_disable(double aDisabled)
{

    if (aDisabled == 1) {

        // Save the initial state
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSTICKYKEYS, sizeof(STICKYKEYS), &g_StartupStickyKeys, 0);
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETTOGGLEKEYS, sizeof(TOGGLEKEYS), &g_StartupToggleKeys, 0);
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFILTERKEYS, sizeof(FILTERKEYS), &g_StartupFilterKeys, 0);

        STICKYKEYS skOff = g_StartupStickyKeys;
        if( (skOff.dwFlags & SKF_STICKYKEYSON) == 0 ) {
            // Disable the hotkey and the confirmation
            skOff.dwFlags &= ~SKF_HOTKEYACTIVE;
            skOff.dwFlags &= ~SKF_CONFIRMHOTKEY;

            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS, sizeof(STICKYKEYS), &skOff, 0);
        }

        TOGGLEKEYS tkOff = g_StartupToggleKeys;
        if( (tkOff.dwFlags & TKF_TOGGLEKEYSON) == 0 ) {
            // Disable the hotkey and the confirmation
            tkOff.dwFlags &= ~TKF_HOTKEYACTIVE;
            tkOff.dwFlags &= ~TKF_CONFIRMHOTKEY;

            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETTOGGLEKEYS, sizeof(TOGGLEKEYS), &tkOff, 0);
        }

        FILTERKEYS fkOff = g_StartupFilterKeys;
        if( (fkOff.dwFlags & FKF_FILTERKEYSON) == 0 ) {
            // Disable the hotkey and the confirmation
            fkOff.dwFlags &= ~FKF_HOTKEYACTIVE;
            fkOff.dwFlags &= ~FKF_CONFIRMHOTKEY;

            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFILTERKEYS, sizeof(FILTERKEYS), &fkOff, 0);
        }

        _AccessKeysDisabled = true;
        return 1;

    } else {

        // Restore access keys    
        STICKYKEYS sk = g_StartupStickyKeys;
        TOGGLEKEYS tk = g_StartupToggleKeys;
        FILTERKEYS fk = g_StartupFilterKeys;

        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS, sizeof(STICKYKEYS), &g_StartupStickyKeys, 0);
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETTOGGLEKEYS, sizeof(TOGGLEKEYS), &g_StartupToggleKeys, 0);
        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFILTERKEYS, sizeof(FILTERKEYS), &g_StartupFilterKeys, 0);

        _AccessKeysDisabled = false;
        return 1;

    }
}
```

I also handle the WM_CLOSE message in order to restore back the keys,

```
case WM_CLOSE:      

if (_AccessKeysDisabled == true) {
    accesskeys_disable(0);      
}
DestroyWindow(windowHandle);
```

Comment: `SystemParametersInfo` changes the state of the entire machine, as if the user performed the same action thru the Windows GUI. So you are getting exactly what you asked for!